# OpenAi not returning result and exited with code=0

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, openai-api

I'm trying to use OpenAI, but I can't get a result. I'm accessing the API via Visual Studio Code. I have downloaded these extensions for Visual Studio Code: Code Runner and Python. I've also installed OpenAI via CMD: `pip install openai`.

Here's my code:

```py
import os
import openai
openai.api_key = os.getenv("sk-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
x=openai.Completion.create(
  engine="text-davinci-002",
  prompt="Say this is a test",
  max_tokens=5
)
print(x)
```

Referenced from the official documentation: https://beta.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions/create?lang=python

But when I run that code, the output tab is not outputting anything:
[image: Photos]

Anyone know where I possibly went wrong?

Comment: maybe run it in normal console/terminal (`python script.py`) and maybe it will display some error messages.

Comment: as for me in system you should have defined environment's variable `OPEN_API_KEY=sk-5kyIzSG6wxeCDdf2T3BlbdfJxgdfeet9JWm8cQumrG` and use exactly `openai.api_key = os.getenv("OPEN_API_KEY")` or you should put value directly in code without `getenv` - like `openai.api_key = "sk-5kyIzSG6wxeCDdf2T3BlbdfJxgdfeet9JWm8cQumrG"`

Comment: Yea I think you just leaked your OpenAI key

Answer (score 4):

When I run your code in console/terminal/bash (on Linux) without `VSCode` then I get some useful error message. So maybe first you should test it on `CMD` to see if you get error message with explanation.

---

But main problem is that you use `API_KEY` in wrong way

You should use it directly in code (without `os.getenv()`)

```
openai.api_key = "sk-5kyIzSG6wxeCDdf2T3BlbdfJxgdfeet9JWm8cQumrG"
```

Or in system you should set environment's variable

```
OPEN_API_KEY=sk-5kyIzSG6wxeCDdf2T3BlbdfJxgdfeet9JWm8cQumrG
```

and use exactly `OPEN_API_KEY`

```
openai.api_key = os.getenv("OPEN_API_KEY")
```

(and this way you can share code without sharing `API_KEY`)

---

Your `API_KEY` is too short but I tested it with my `API_KEY` and it works for me.

```
import openai

openai.api_key = "sk-...my_api_key..."

x = openai.Completion.create(
  engine="text-davinci-002",
  prompt="Say this is a test",
  max_tokens=5
)

print(x)
```

Result:

```
{
  "choices": [
    {
      "finish_reason": "length",
      "index": 0,
      "logprobs": null,
      "text": "\n\nThis is a"
    }
  ],
  "created": 1652054180,
  "id": "cmpl-55l36Li5BTrRZWPU38MdQai8yVGEA",
  "model": "text-davinci:002",
  "object": "text_completion"
}
```

Comment: I have matched the correction, but still don't work. 
Console Image Error Message : https://imgur.com/a/MluDpyd
My Code : https://imgur.com/a/OPDNabR
Error Message : openai.error.AuthenticationError: No API key provided. You can set your API key in code using 'openai.api_key = <API-KEY>', or you can set the environment variable OPENAI_API_KEY=<API-KEY>).

Comment: did you put correct `API_KEY` directly as string  `openai.api_key = "sk-5kyIzSG6wxeCDdf2T3BlbdfJxgdfeet9JWm8cQumrG"` ? If you use `os.getenv("sk-5kyIzSG6wxeCDdf2T3BlbdfJxgdfeet9JWm8cQumrG)` then it can't find environment variable with name `"sk-5kyIzSG6wxeCDdf2T3BlbdfJxgdfeet9JWm8cQumrG"` and `getenv()` gives `None` and finally you get `openai.api_key = None` and this gives me exactly the same error. But I tested code with your API_KEY and it is too short - and maybe you should generate new `API_KEY`

Comment: This was a really helpful answer. Here I was about to waste my time trying to submit GET requests. 
Though they work, it was a much longer approach.
For reference:
`import requests  
  
# Set the API endpoint and headers  
endpoint = "https://api.openai.com/v1/models"  
headers = {  
    "Content-Type": "application/json",  
    "Authorization": "Bearer API_KEY"  
}  
# Make the GET request  
response = requests.get(endpoint, headers=headers)  
# Print the response status code  
print(response.status_code)  
# Print the response content  
print(response.content)`

Answer (score 0):

```
import openai

import os

from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv

_ = load_dotenv(find_dotenv())

os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY'] = 'sk-qX8fYeuOxPtse7ZXgNgsT3BlbkFJETitXKSk4F32G7bXG5'
```

or

```
openai.api_key = 'sk-qX8fYeuOxPtse7ZXgNgsT3BlbkFJETitXKSk4F32G7bXG5'
```

Note- Find key here https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76137060/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).